# Name of the isomorphism between the different way to parenthesize a product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

The different ways to parenthesize a Cartesian product are all isomorphic, allowing us to speak of "the" Cartesian product of n objects.

$$A\times (B\times C) \simeq (A\times B)\times C$$

Said otherwise, once we choose two ways of parenthesizing, the cartesian structure yields an isomorphism.

In general, the name of the isomorphism between
$$\otimes_{i\in I} f_i  \simeq \otimes_{j\in J} g_j$$

where $I$ and $J$ are ordered sets, $f_I$ is a composable family of morphisms  $\forall i,i+1 \in I~ cod(f_i) = dom(f_{i+1})$,  $g_J$is a composable family of morphisms $\forall j,j+1 \in J~ cod(g_j) = dom(g_{j+1})$, and those families are equal on common index $f_{I\Delta J} = g_{I \Delta J}$, and identity at non-common index $f_{I - J} = 1_{I-J}$, $g_{J-I} = 1_{J-I}$

Do such isomorphism have a name in "ordinary" mathematics (beside *associators* in category theory)

Comment: They are called associators.

Comment: Are they called that way in non-category theory context as well ?

Comment: Since some related area have been extensively studied before CT (catalan numbers) I imagined there was some other terminology (more intuitive to non CT folks)

Comment: This is paradigmatic abstract nonsense, no good combinatorialist would deign to have given it a name :)

Comment: @KevinArlin not untrue. I'll go with associators (although traditionally it refers only to one generator, not the whole family)